# Matching two types to determine type parameters

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros

I'm writing some macros in Scala.

Let's assume I have some `Type`, e.g. `typeOf[Map[String,Set[Int]]]` and a similar type where some of its parts have been replaced with undetermined type parameters, e.g. `typeOf[Map[String,Set[T]]]` where `T` is unknown.

How do I match these two types with each other to find out that `T` is `Int`?

Answer (score 0):

`typeArgs` property return the list of type parameters. If I correctly understood what do you need:

```
val mapParams = typeOf[Map[String, Set[Int]]].typeArgs // List(String, Set[Int])
val setType = mapParams.drop(1).head                   // Set[Int]
val setParam = setType.typeArgs.head                   // Int
```

Comment: That was just an example. I want a general method that would work for all types :)

Comment: In that case you could match over `typeArgs` and recursively go deeper. I don't think scala has any easier way of matching types, although I could be mistaken.

Comment: that would be easy if it was just for type arguments. There are also singleton types, refined types, variance comes into play, etc. This is probably not trivial to write by hand.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use quasiquotes  doc:http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/syntax-summary.html

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

tq"Map[Int,Int]" match {
  case tq"Map[Int,$t2]" => t2
}

tq"Map[Int,Seq[Int]]" match {
  case tq"Map[Int,Seq[$t2]]" => t2
}
```